# Comparing PFObject and AnyObject - Parse.com + iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I am creating an iOS application using **Swift** and **Parse.com**

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` filled with cells of 'posts'. To show the options button on only posts that were created by the currently-logged-in user, I want to check if the post's "fromUser" attribute (which is a pointer to _User table) is the same as the current user.

The below code does not work though...get the error "cannot compare PFObject with AnyObject"

```
// Show options button if post by user
if post["fromUser"] == PFUser.currentUser() {

    self.optionsButton.hidden = false

}
```

How can I do this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare with the `objectId` which is **Unique Id** of the user

```
// Show options button if post by user
if post["fromUser"]["objectId"] == PFUser.currentUser().objectId() {

    self.optionsButton.hidden = false

}
```

Comment: Can also just use post["fromUser"].objectId()

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code

```
    var fromUser = post["fromUser"] as PFUser
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() as PFUser

    // Show options button if post by user
    if fromUser == currentUser {

        self.optionsButton.hidden = false

    }
```